# Trying to get asynchronous functionality with glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I have this code:

[image]

Which receive 2 args, the first is `script`, it's only a linux command, and the other is `template`, it's only a string that gives what html template wants to use an user.

this `appCreator` has 3 methods, the first with the comment `// remove template from app` will remove one html template from the app folder.

Another with the comment `// copying template` only copy a template from `TEMPLATE_FOLDER` on `APP_FOLDER` folder.

And the last one is with the comment `// getting all html files`, only find all the html on a explicite template from the app folder, and replace the text `PASTEROCK_SCRIPT` from the html, putting the script text.

This code works... Nice, but not appropriately, because the synchronous javascript does not respect the functionality.

[image]

With the numbers, you can check the way how is running... And I want to respect the order... Something like this:

[image]

How can I resolve it?

With async and await I tried:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as glob from "glob";
import { ncp } from "ncp";
import * as rimraf from "rimraf";

export default async function appCreator(script: string, template: string) {
  const APP_FOLDER = `${__dirname}/../app/${template}/`;
  const TEMPLATE_FOLDER = `${__dirname}/../template/${template}/`;

  // remove template from app
  if (fs.existsSync(APP_FOLDER)) {
    await rimraf.sync(APP_FOLDER);
  }

  // copying template
  await ncp(TEMPLATE_FOLDER, APP_FOLDER, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  // getting all html files
  await glob.sync(`${APP_FOLDER}**/*.html`).map(file => {
    // reading html file
    const readFile = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: "utf8" });
    let replace: string | number = readFile.search("PASTEROCK_SCRIPT");

    if (replace !== -1) {
      replace = readFile.replace("PASTEROCK_SCRIPT", script);

      fs.writeFileSync(file, replace, { encoding: "utf8" });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: await “did not work” how?

Comment: @Ry, I've edited the question including how I used await...

Comment: `await` doesn’t make sync functions async. It needs to operate on a promise, so you need versions of `rimraf` (not `rimraf.sync`), `glob` (not `glob.sync`), and `fs.read/writeFile` that return promises. fs ones are in `fs.promises`. Promise-returning functions can be created from callbacks with [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: @Ry, those functions do not return any promise... I needed to follow the typical way through function as a arg.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains a ton of code in pictures which are not searchable. It has an answer but it is a self-answer (and of mediocre quality in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

The packages I use do not support promises... So this is the solution if someone wants to know. The package `rimraf` is not necessary because `ncp` replace all.

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import { ncp } from "ncp";
import * as glob from "glob";

export default function appCreator(script: string, template: string) {
  const APP_FOLDER = `${__dirname}/../app/${template}/`;
  const TEMPLATE_FOLDER = `${__dirname}/../template/${template}/`;

  // copying or replacing template
  ncp(TEMPLATE_FOLDER, APP_FOLDER, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    // getting all html files
    glob.sync(`${APP_FOLDER}**/*.html`).map(file => {
      // reading html file
      const readFile = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: "utf8" });
      let replace: string | number = readFile.search("PASTEROCK_SCRIPT");

      if (replace !== -1) {
        replace = readFile.replace("PASTEROCK_SCRIPT", script);

        fs.writeFileSync(file, replace, { encoding: "utf8" });
      }
    });
  });
}
```